# pt-query-digest filter queries by user and database

Tags: mysql, percona

This is working but not filtering by user/database

```
pt-query-digest /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log --since="$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '1 day ago')" --user=phpmyadmin --database=my_table --limit 20
```

This returns error

```
pt-query-digest /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log --since="$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d '1 day ago')" --limit 20 --filter '$event->{db} eq "my_table" && $event->{user} =~ /phpmyadmin/'
```

error

```
Pipeline process 12 (filter) caused an error: Use of uninitialized value in string eq at (eval 33) line 1, <$fh> line 149273.
Will retry pipeline process 11 (filter) 100 more times.
Pipeline process 12 (filter) caused an error: Use of uninitialized value in string eq at (eval 33) line 1, <$fh> line 149274.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Are you're using the {db} attribute to filter by tables ("my_table")? Try to run something like this to see available attributes for your input:

```
pt-query-digest                    \
slow-queries160201.log             \
--filter 'print Dumper $event'  \
--no-report                        \
--sample 1
```

This will print a list of arguments like `Lock_time => '0.000026'` that you can use to filter. You probably can't filer by table.

2 - Try this:

```
--filter '(($event->{db} || "") =~ m/mydb/) && ($event->{user} || "") =~ m/myuser/)'
```